# UIPanGestureRecognizer sliding UIView animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I know there have been many answers to questions like this and many libraries on GitHub but I just I want to keep it light and simple.  I just want to move the menu out and make it follow my finger.  That part works but the view doesn't slide out initially smoothly...it just appears where my finger is.  Here's what I have:

```
//viewDidLoad
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panSettings = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
[panSettings setDelegate:self];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panSettings];

UIView *container = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
//...drop shadows and such...
[self.view addSubview:_container];

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    CGPoint velocity = [sender velocityInView:self.view];
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
    if (velocity.x < 0 && translation.x < -50) {
        if (_container.frame.origin.x != 0) {
            panCoord = [sender locationInView:self.view];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                _container.frame = CGRectMake(panCoord.x-100, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
            }];
        }
    }
}
```

Handling the pan:I want to check which way the slide is going, checking for how long and checking the location of the container.  I want to make it slide out smoothly to the finger location once the swipe goes left farther negative then -50...any advice?

Comment: Where's your UIView animation?

Comment: @SantaClaus I tried it with UIView animation also and it still had the same effect of just appearing at the finger location.

Comment: You can also do that stuff using Touch methods(i.e. Touch began, Touch moved, touch ended)

Comment: @yourwish I saw those examples...to use touch events, I need to subclass a UIView and add those methods in that subclass?  Because I couldn't get the touch events to work in `self.view`

Comment: Use your own created delegate methods for notify another class about your touch.

Answer (score 1):

I used :

```
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *sgr = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:)];
  sgr.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:sgr];
```

check it out maybe it's easier

Comment: Thanks, I understand that would be easier but that defeats the purpose of being able to drag the view across the screen.